# Why is android project not opening properly in Android Studio?

Tags: android, ide

Why is android project not opening properly in Android Studio? 
I have an android project, set up as such

[image]

However, when I open it on android studio,
The structure is setup up as such
[image]

Having understood that the project is from an eclipse ide, I tried to open the file, and then export it, however I get this error:

`Project 'freegemas-android' is missing project dependency '/freegemas' in Eclipse workspace.`

Comment: Which version of android studio you use?

Comment: @user4618535  The project you showed at Git is made in Eclipse. See how to open it in Android Studios: [LINK](http://rexstjohn.com/exporting-android-project-eclipse-android-studio-0-4-0/)

Comment: Android Studio 1.1.0

Comment: It's because the project opened was compiled by Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Export from Eclipse

1.Update your Eclipse ADT Plugin (you must have version 22.0 or higher).

2.In Eclipse, select File > Export.

3.In the window that appears, open Android and select Generate Gradle build files.

4.Select the projects you want to export for Android Studio and click Finish.

Your selected projects remain in the same location but now contain a build.gradle file and are ready for Android Studio.

Import into Android Studio

1.In Android Studio, select File > Import Project.

2.Locate a project you exported from Eclipse, select the project's root directory and click OK.

3.Select Create project from existing sources and click Next.

4.Follow the walk-through to complete the import process.

Comment: What is the cause of this error:  Project 'freegemas-android' is missing project dependency '/freegemas' in Eclipse workspace.

Comment: Are you using any other libraries in the project like maven or something like that?

Comment: Not that I know of.
Link to the project: https://github.com/siondream/freegemas-gdx